# Running Intellij as User

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I am facing a strange problem running Intellij on ubuntu... When I start it as root , the program will run , but when I try run it as user its screen will freeze to load page and will not go further. 
I have taken care of privileges , and its the first time it is happening becouse  everyday it was running perfectly.

I took a screen for showing you guys what messages are printed in terminal when I start it . 
[image]

And here is a screen that shows when the startup stops.
[image]

Any tip on how to solve this would be very helpful , Thank you for your time

Comment: Where did you install IntelliJ?

Comment: opt / intellij @Harmelodic

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely that your root user doesn't have intelliJ settings.  Notice:

```
$ ls ~ -alh | grep .IntelliJ 
drwxrwxr-x    4 me  me  4.0K Apr 29 03:31 .IntelliJIdea2016.1
```

but

```
$ sudo ls /root | grep .IntelliJ
```

produces nothing

Root cause aside... you should not be running it as root to begin with.  Likely another way around what you're trying to accomplish.  Post a link to another question with the issue and I'll assist.

Comment: Yesterday it was not working , and today it works fine , I didnt change anything ... Strange @TomSchober

Comment: And now it is not working again , after patches and restart. 
I tryed the above comands and the result produced is exactly as you say for both commands. 
And I am searching for this issue but could not find a link

Comment: Is there a good reason you are trying to run it as root to begin with?  My suggestion is that NOT doing that is the solution.  Whatever it is that needs root access should be executed as a super user.  If you're having problems running iJ as a normal user, then it's possible some of the assets it needs require a change in permissions.

Comment: I am running it as a root only becouse i cant run it as simple user. And I think permissions are ok , since IntelliJ was running as user before  this...

Comment: You think it might be any plugin that causes this ?